# Is The Force Awakens filmed in 3D, or post-processed?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

I note that The Force Awakens is available in 3D or 2D. Was it filmed in 3D or is this a post-processed add on?

Comment: Honestly you can tell by watching it that it's post prod 3D. The 3d-ishness has quite prominent "layers" in some of the scenes.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to find out *before* watching one or the other!

Comment: I just told you, just decide what you want. I have seen it both ways and either way is fine. 3D is probably more fun either post prod or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this ScreenCrush article](http://screencrush.com/star-wars-the-force-awakens-imax-theaters/) from October 2015,

> *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*, on the other hand, is **available in post-converted 3D**, with no 3D 70mm option (except for theaters equipped with IMAX with Laser, of which there are only 6 in the U.S.).

Essentially, the 3D is a post-processed add-on because of the choice to film parts of the film with IMAX cameras.

Comment: The answer is right. Although it seems to confuse 70mm film and laser imax which is a digital projection system.

Comment: @JeremyFrench : Me or the article?  I have no confusion about these things.  :-)

Comment: Sorry. The linked article seems to confuse these things.

Comment: @JeremyFrench : Hehe, no worries.  :-)

Comment: wow, that article totally confused me!? I think the answer is basically that unless you're in a very select few cinemas you'll be watching a crappy post-processed 2.5D film, not 3D?

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.slashfilm.com/star-wars-7-imax-2/) from SlashFilm.com confirms that

### **SW:TFA was shot in IMAX**.

First we have the following picture from a [tweet from Bad Robot](https://twitter.com/bad_robot/status/486628757780721664/photo/1):

[image]

Then a quote from IMAX:

> We emailed an IMAX rep, who said the following: “All we can say at this point is that we can confirm that JJ Abrams is using the IMAX camera for Star Wars: Episode VII.” They also confirmed it is shooting film. So while Abrams made a big deal of shooting Episode VII in 35mm, he’s going even bigger too: 70mm IMAX.
>
> This isn’t really a big surprise. A few months ago, IMAX announced that  Episode VII was being released in IMAX. But that didn’t mean it was being shot in IMAX. These days, almost every big film gets an IMAX release, but only one or two a year are actually shot in the format. We can now confirm Episode VII will be shot and released in IMAX.